# Django 1.9 : Pass variables from python script to bash script - OSError : [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, django

```
subprocess.call(["echo",instance.Username])  # => works .


subprocess.call(["username=",instance.Username])  # => error
subprocess.Call(["username","=",instance.Username])  # => error

subprocess.call(["username=",instance.Username],shell=True)
# => no Error but when i do echo $username there is nothing inside..
```

would you help me, I just want to put the value of instance.Username in a bash variable.

Thank you.

Comment: You'll have to give more details. Exactly what are you going to do with that "bash variable", and where?

Comment: I will need it to execute another bash script..
for the moment, I just want to put the value of instance.Username in a bash variable that i can display in my terminal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to pass it as an environment variable to `subprocess.call()` like so:

```
env = {
    'username': instance.Username,
}

subprocess.call(['./your_script.sh'], env=env)
```

This will make the environment variable `$username` available to your bash script.

Remember to enclose the bash command in a list, run the script with `./`, and start the script with the correct shebang, (all things I forgot to do while writing this).

Comment: I tried this :    
env = {
                        'username': instance.Username,
}

                subprocess.call(['echo'], env=env)
it return nothing.

Comment: Of course it won't return anything. You need `subprocess.check_output` for that.

Comment: sorry, I wanted to say that when i do subprocess.call(['echo'], env=env , it gives me a blank line !!

Comment: Of course; you're not echoing anything.  If you want to echo something from the environment, you'd need to name it as normal.  `subprocess.call(['echo', '$username'], env={'username':'AdamBarnes'})`.

Comment: I messed up my last comment.  The command should have been `subprocess.call('echo $username', env={'username':'AdamBarnes'}, shell=True)`.  Note that you won't need `shell=True` when calling your script, and you shouldn't use `shell=True` if you're ever passing user-supplied data to `subprocess.call()`.